# Is it correct to say "I and none of my friends are able to cook Chinese food"?

Tags: verb-agreement, negation

Is it correct to say "I and none of my friends are able to cook Chinese food"?

I was wondering how I can say that I was not able to do something, and none of my friends were able to either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would seem more appropriately worded, especially in written form, as this: Neither my friends nor I can cook Chinese food. "[Chinese] food" is a mass noun here, so you do not use the article "a" prior.

If you want something informal: I can't cook Chinese food and neither can my friends.

Comment: thanks for your great answer but I was wondering can I say this sentence using "None of my friends" statement or not?

Comment: If you simply want to use that clause, then sure, we can make it work. "None of my friends nor I can cook Chinese food"; "None of my friends can cook Chinese food and neither can I"; "I can't cook Chinese food and none of my friends can either"; "I and none of my friends are able to cook Chinese food."

Comment: Is "food" plural? Not uncountable?